# Angular keeps refreshing while no changes were done

Tags: angular, loops, debugging, angular-material, storybook

I am writting stories for my lib that turn a json schema into something more visual ( https://github.com/jy95/ngx-json-schema-viewer ). In the testing process, I encountered a strange issue - the component seems to keep refreshing while no changes were done (making impossible to see the content behind accordion) :

[image]
(Example on https://master--65174c82cd070b9998efd7f6.chromatic.com/?path=/story/viewer-object--properties )

While I looked up the source code closely, I can't see what caused this to happen.

```js
    import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
    import { ChangeDetectionStrategy, Component, Input, forwardRef } from '@angular/core';
    
    import {
      CreateEdgeComponent
    } from "../../common/index";
    
    import type { JSONSchemaNS, JSONSchema } from "../../types";
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'jse-object-properties',
      standalone: true,
      imports: [
        CommonModule,
        forwardRef(() => CreateEdgeComponent)
      ],
      changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
      template: `
        <ul>
          <ng-container *ngFor="let entry of propertiesEntries">
            <jse-common-create-edge [schema]="entry[1]" [required]="isRequired(entry[0])">
              <strong name>
                {{ generatePropertyName(entry[0]) }}
              </strong>
            </jse-common-create-edge>
          </ng-container>
        </ul>
      `,
    })
    export class CreatePropertiesComponent {
      @Input({ required: true }) schema!: JSONSchemaNS.Object;
    
      get propertiesEntries() : [string, JSONSchema][] {
        return Object.entries(this.schema.properties || {});
      }
    
      generatePropertyName(key: string): string {
        return `${key}`;
      }
    
      isRequired(key: string): boolean {
        return Array.isArray(this.schema.required) ? this.schema.required.includes(key) : false;
      }
    }
```

Angular version :

```bash
Angular CLI: 16.2.6
Node: 18.18.0
Package Manager: npm 9.8.1
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 16.2.9
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1602.6
@angular-devkit/build-angular   16.2.6
@angular-devkit/core            16.2.6
@angular-devkit/schematics      16.2.6
@angular/cli                    16.2.6
@angular/material               16.2.8
@schematics/angular             16.2.6
ng-packagr                      16.2.3
rxjs                            7.8.1
typescript                      5.1.6
zone.js                         0.13.3
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: easy fix - use `keyvalue` pipe instead of `propertiesEntries`

Comment: @Andrei thanks, will try and see if it works. I'm curious to find out why

Comment: most likely your `CreateEdgeComponent` contains `.then` or `setTimeout` hacks or simmilar async things.

Comment: I don't have enough information to assess the problem but I recommend the following: Eliminate any call to a function like isRequired() from the view or replace it with a pipe.